# How to avoid unnecessary preconditions in unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing

Ideally, a test class is written for every class in the production code. In test class, all the test methods may not require the same preconditions. How do we solve this problem?
Do we create separate test classes for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating separate methods wrapping necessary *precondition setup*. Do not confuse this approach with traditional *test setup*. As an example, assume you wrote tests for receipt provider, which searches repository and depending on some validation steps, returns receipt. We might end-up with:

- receipt doesn't exist in repository: return null
- receipt exists, but doesn't match validator date: return null
- receipt exists, matches validator date, but was not fully committed (i.e. was not processed by some external system): return null

We have several conditions here: receipt exists/doesn't exist, receipt is invalid date-wise, receipt is not commited. Our *happy path* is the default setup (for example done via traditional test setup). Then, happy path test would be as simple as (some C# pseudo-code):

```
[Test]
public void GetReceipt_ReturnsReceipt()
{
    receiptProvider.GetReceipt("701").IsNotNull();
}
```

Now, for the special condition cases we simply write tiny, dedicated methods that would arrange our test environment (eg. setup dependencies) so that conditions are met:

```
[Test]
public void GetReceipt_ReturnsNull_WhenReceiptDoesntExist()
{
    ReceiptDoesNotExistInRepository("701")
    receiptProvider.GetReceipt("701").IsNull();
}

[Test]
public void GetReceipt_ReturnsNull_WhenExistingReceiptHasInvalidDate()
{
    ReceiptHasInvalidDate("701");
    receiptProvider.GetReceipt("701").IsNull();
}
```

You'll end up with couple extra helper methods, but your tests will be much easier to read and understand. This is especially helpful when logic is more complicated than simple yes-no setup:

```
[Test]
public void GetReceipt_ThrowsException_WhenUncommittedReceiptHasInvalidDate()
{
    ReceiptHasInvalidDate("701");
    ReceiptIsUncommitted("701");
    receiptProvider.GetReceipt("701").Throws<Exception>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In this case, there won't be any traditional setup. Do you think a class exhibits some kinda design problem if you cannot have common setup?

Comment: @sundar: not necessarily. Even having single dependency might require different setups depending on dependency behavior (result, exception, etc.). Multiple dependencies might complicate setups further. I'd say it's rather common.

Answer (score 1):

It's an option to group tests with the same preconditions in the same classes, this also helps avoiding test classes of over a thousand lines. You can also group the creation of the preconditions in seperate methods and let each test call the applicable method. You can do this when most of the methods have different preconditions, otherwise you could just use a setup method that is called before the test.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a Setup method that will get called before each test runs. In this method I instantiate the class I want to test, giving it any dependencies it needs to be created. Then I will set the specific details for the individual tests inside the test method. It moves any common initialization of the class out to the setup method and allows the test to be focused on what it needs to be evaluated.

You may find this link valuable, it discusses an approach to Test Setups:
[In Defense of Test Setup Methods, by Erik Dietrich](http://www.daedtech.com/in-defense-of-test-setup-methods)